# How to add keypress event on option element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to add an event listener to option elements of particular select elements. But it's not working.

HTML:

```
<form id='form1' method='post' name='form1'>
   <select class="form-control big-input-h4" id="tnvffoewr">
      <option>select an option</option>
      <option>o2</option>
      <option>o3</option>
      <option>o4</option>
      <option>add new item</option>
   </select>
   <button type='submit'>submit</button>
   <button type='reset'>reset</button>
</form>
<form id='form2' method='post' name='form2'>
   <select class="form-control big-input-h4" id="tnvffoewr">
      <option>select an option</option>
      <option>o2</option>
      <option>o3</option>
      <option>o4</option>
      <option value='add'>add new item</option>
   </select>
   <button type='submit'>submit</button>
   <button type='reset'>reset</button>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
Array.from($('#tnvffoewr').children().slice(1,-1)).forEach(element => {
        console.log(element.text)
        element.addEventListener('keypress',(e)=>{
            console.log('clck')
            if(e.key=='Enter'){
            console.log('enter')
           }
        })
    });
$('#tnvffoewr').on('change',(e)=>{
   if(e.target.value == 'add'){
      window.location.href = '/add_new';
   }
});
```

I want event to be triggered on every option except first and last when enter is pressed. If I just apply keypress on select its working but I want the events to be triggered when I press enter on option.

Edit 1-

What I am trying to do is when I press enter on an option I want to click a submit button. But keep in mind to open the drop-down we press enter that shouldn't submit the form so we cannot add the event listener to the select element. But after the drop-down is opened and then suppose I go to 3rd option and press enter that value should be selected and then the form should be submitted, each select corresponds to its own seperate form. We cannot use `on('change')` as we can change the option by arrow keys, also there is another function which is executed on change. So I need it to execute this seperate function `on('keypress')` when I press enter to select an option. As a matter of fact I just need to understand how would I add a `on('keypress')` event to option submitting I can manage.

I have kept the same id because when I provide that id to any select I want it to work the same way. If you want you can give an answer with same class name works for me.

Also as @freedomn-m asked, clicking should do the same thing as pressing enter, I just assumed that I can add `click` event the same way as `keypress` event, but again we cannot use the `change` event. We cannot disable the options because we have to select a option. 1st option is kind of first label you see when the page is loaded. Last option opens another form to add new item to the options list, which is working fine and it runs on `change` event.

Edit 2 -

What I want to do is have a select which can do two things.

1. When select changes to add new item go to the link `'/add_new'`
2. If enter is pressed in drop-down-list on any option except first and last submit the form after changing the select value. Pressing enter on the select should do the default action of opening the drop-down-list.

Comment: Enter on an `<option>` is `change` on the `select`

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you're trying to achieve through this that you can't achieve any other way?   Have you tried disabling the options so they can't be selected?  Is it only that you want enter disabled on first/last but still be selectable with a click?

Comment: @freedomn-m I have edited the question and added my requirement. I hope it clarifies my needs, and what I really want to do.

Comment: *there is another function which is executed on change* - FYI you can have as many `$(..).on("change", ..` event handlers as you can type

Comment: it seems something we are not told in regard to the focus on keypress enter. is it perhaps the actual select element is a hidden field and a fancy boxes with css overlaid on top to provide interaction and they need enter key?

Comment: @BagusTesa only if you use a third-party drop-down-list replacement.   Otherwise `<select>` UI is handled by the browser (different implementation per browser), which is why it's so hard to affect it with css/keyboard.

Comment: @freedomn-m thats what i'm worried about. i had misgivings with the way the problem presented. initially i thought it was a misunderstanding compounded with badly written jquery+native js concoction.

Comment: @freedomn-m as I mentioned we can change values with arrow up and down without actually pressing enter, in such a case I don't want the second function to execute as there is a change event listener already working, for demonstration purpose a simple ```console.log(option.text)``` or ```console.log('enter pressed on option')``` 2nd function will suffice. The function should work if I am pressing enter on the drop-down list on option, excluding the first and last options. Second thing it's not a fancy box or a hidden field, it's a simple html ```<select>``` not a third party drop-down-list.

Comment: @freedomn-m For simplicity sake I have added ```<form>``` and the ```on('change')``` event. And I have even added another edit to clarify what exactly I want to do.

Answer (score -1):

You should only allow one id for each html element to avoid confusion and browser will only accept the first occurence of the id.

```
<select class="form-control big-input-h4 tnvffoewr">
   <option>select an option</option>
   <option>o2</option>
   <option>o3</option>
   <option>o4</option>
   <option>add new item</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control big-input-h4 tnvffoewr">
   <option>select an option</option>
   <option>o2</option>
   <option>o3</option>
   <option>o4</option>
   <option>add new item</option>
</select>
```

Next, you can do something like:

```
$(".tnvffoewr").on("keypress", function(e){
  if(e.which !== 13)
   return;
  
  var sel = $(this).val();
  if(sel === 'select an option' || sel === 'add new item')
   return;
  
  alert(sel);
});
```

It will alert the index of the selected option when you press enter on other than the first and last options, you can then filter it using `if`s. It is still a bit awkward given that the `select` box need to be focused (by either clicking it or using `tab`).

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6stpdmj5/

Comment: Sorry but we cannot use on change because there is another function which runs when we change select. I need the new function to run when I press enter and select an option

Comment: @IndrajeetSinghYadav you can stack `change` event as much as you wanted.

Comment: I know we can but the second function shouldn't run on change it needs to run when I press enter on option excluding the first and last option.

Comment: @IndrajeetSinghYadav i'm not sure the use case, i've updated the code to capture the event should you press enter key **on the `select` box** whenever anything but the first and the last item selected. but really, this way the event wont fire if you use click to select stuff though.

Comment: I have edited the question and the code for more clarity I hope that helps you understand the use case. And the edit you provided gave me an idea I will try to implement it and let you know how it goes. It's a workaround I had in mind but I wanted to see if there is a way to apply the ```keypress``` event to the ```option``` element.

Comment: @IndrajeetSinghYadav if that is the case, `$(".tnvffoewr option").on("click",...` might work. but it disregard enter key press, adding `.on("keypress",..` doesn't work for `option` (not sure why). you should register keyboard events on the `select` box instead.

Comment: Yes ```.on('keypress',...``` works on select. Oh I was also wondering why doesn't it work on ```option```. Then any answer to help me with the 2nd point of edit 2 is welcome as an answer. I am open to third party or a fancy select element too.